# Is it possible to code search engine in beautiful Soup

Tags: python, linux, search, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup for parsing web pages. 
Are there any functions in BS which i can use i making search engine or crawling the website to index it in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, BeautifulSoup is not a search engine. It is also not a Swiss Army knife, nor can it make you a sandwich. You will need a database (preferably one that's optimized for search, like Sphinx or Lucene) to do that.